# Error (VSCode warning) after replacing alternate of getClass() in php

Tags: php, deprecated, deprecation-warning

As you know, `getClass()` has been deprecated in PHP 8. So I replaced it with `->getType()->getName()`  (another option is `::Class`) but after this change, VS Code warned for `newInstance()`

`Call to a member function newInstance() on a non-object of type stringPHP(PHP0404)`

is this an error or it is OK?

[image: 1]

the full code is as follow:

```
$body = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$mClass = $methodParams[count($methodParams) - 1]->getType()->getName();//::Class;//getClass();
$mdl = $mClass->newInstance($body);
```

Comment: How do you think `newInstance()` is supposed to be called? (is there some documentation for example)

Comment: I have a method parameters array, that has 2 elements. I want to add `$mdl` as its third element.

Comment: Who is `getName()`? [This](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionnamedtype.getname.php)? The error message says very clear. The values of [type `string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) are not objects, therefore `->` does not make sense for them (and they do not have the method `newInstance()` because they do not have methods in the first place).

Comment: @axiac I've changed second line to `$mClass = new ReflectionClass($methodParams[count($methodParams) - 1])` and the error gone. since getClass() is a ReflectionClass I changed to this. is that a valid code?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you. I have never used reflection. Unless you are writing a tool for development (let's say, something like PHPUnit), using reflection is a sign of a bad application design. Improve the design and the need of reflection disappears.